# ¿Por qué no me muestra Autocomplete?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Buen día, tengo un `<input>` de un Modal donde se colocan Nombres de Materiales, esto para guardarlos en una Base de Datos, el cual se me ocurrió la idea de utilizar `autocomplete();` en jQuery consultando los Materiales ya guardados en la base de Datos asi como para dar una sugerencia al momento que el usuario escriba nombres de Materiales, el problema es que no me muestra el autocomplete.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si lo coloco a otro `<input>` fuera del Modal, me muestra el `autocomplete();` sin ningún problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por que no se me muestra en el `<input>` del Modal?

Les dejo el código de la consulta y del Modal con el input:

```
<?php
$sql3 = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT nombre_material FROM materiales_planos");
$texto = "";
foreach($sql3 as $intento):
  $texto .= '"' . $intento['nombre_material'] . '",';
endforeach;
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <strong><h4 class="modal-title">Datos del Material</h4></strong>
        </div>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $idplano?>" name="iddelplano" id="iddelplano">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombrematerial" id="nombrematerial" placeholder="Nombre de Material">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidades" id="cantidades" placeholder="Cantidad">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button onclick="actualizar();" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Agregar Material</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Tagsava = [<?php echo $texto?>];
      $("#nombrematerial").autocomplete({
      source: Tagsava
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quita el atributo `tabindex="-1"` del modal, impide que haya ventanas superiores al modal.

Comment: Acabo de quitar el atributo, y sigue sin mostrar el autocomplete.